# Microsoft Graph OAuth doesn't refresh page for outlook.com email when using loginHint

Tags: android, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I used the [Android example](http://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/android) from Microsoft Graph documentation.

When I manually enter a `@outlook.com` email address, it automatically redirects me to the `login.live.com` sign-in page.

When I pass a `loginHint` via the `PublicClientApplication.acquireToken()` method from `MSAL` however, it does not redirect to `login.live.com`. Instead it remains on `login.microsoftonline.com` and reports the email address is invalid.

Is is possible to pass a `loginHint` for personal accounts?

Comment: Can you add the code and uri's you are using? There isn't enough information here to diagnose what is going on.

Comment: Hi! I'm using example from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/android page. I call PublicClientApplication.acquireToken(activity, SCOPES, loginhint, callback);. When I use mail@outlook.com as loginhint it doesn't redirect automatically to login.live.com as if I entered this email in chromewebview textbox manually.

Comment: It looks like this is an issue with either [Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL)](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android) or `login.microsoftonline.com` (which handles the redirect you mention). I've cleaned up and re-tagged the question so the right audience sees this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that passing a `loginHint` to MSAL stays on `login.microsoftonline.com`? Try pasting the below request into a browser as a quick test:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F&response_mode=query&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read&state=12345&login_hint=mail@outlook.com
```

This request correctly redirects to `login.live.com`. But it shows you an error message because the account mail@outlook.com doesn't actually exist.